# react-native-swiper add child dynamically

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-native-swiper

I want to add dynamically component in `<Swiper>`?
Like that:

```js
React.useEffect(()=>{
  setDataArray([...data, newData]); // newData is just an example.
},[index])

return (
  <Swiper
    horizontal={true}
    loop={false}
    onIndexChanged={(i)=>{
      if (i == dataArray.length)
        setIndex(i)
    }}
  >
    {
      dataArray.map((props, i)=>(
        <Swiper_Child
          key={'key_'+i}
          {...props}
        />
      ))
    }
  </Swiper>
);
```

Because when `dataArray` have a new element to create a new `Swiper_child` component, `Swiper` does not change the number of page to swipe...
How to do it ?